# Chart JQuery introduzindo valores de array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Então é o seguinte pessoal, eu tenho 2 variáveis do tipo array que foram convertidas de php para javascript, até aqui tudo ok. Usei alert para ver se mostrava e funcionou. O que eu pretendia era guardar esses 2 arrays dentro da variável data.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript"
src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" > < /script>

  <
  script type = "text/javascript" >

  <?php
$sql2 = "SELECT tag,contador FROM tags";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);

$tagparatudo = array();
$contadorparatudo = array();
while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
  {
  $tagparatudo[] = $row2["tag"];
  $contadorparatudo[] = $row2["contador"];


  }

  $js_array = json_encode($tagparatudo);
  $array2 = json_encode($contadorparatudo);
  echo "var tags = ". $js_array. ";\n";
  echo "var contagem = ". $array2. ";\n";
  ?>

alert(contagem);
alert(tags);



// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Something', 'Here'],
    ['Work', 5],
    ['Newthing', 5],
    ['Newthingz', 5]
  ]);
  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {
    'title': 'Tag Ranks',
    'width': 450,
    'height': 400
  };

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
} <
/script>
```

```html
<div id="piechart"></div>
```

Irá ser criado um google chart com os valores da variável data e o que eu pretendia era algo do gênero :

```
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Something', 'Here'],

um ciclo for{
        [array tags, array contagem]
}
  ]);
```

Comment: Alguém me pode ajudar? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu "alert" está funcionando e mostrando os dados corretamente, então me parece que o que você precisa é ajustar a estrutura dos arrays que você está montando.

Pelo seu exemplo, a variável "data" deve ser um array composto de arrays:

```
[
 ['Something', 'Here'],
 ['Work', 5],
 ['Newthing', 5],
 ['Newthingz', 5]
]
```

E o que você está gerando no PHP > JS são dois arrays diferentes:

```
['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
['Valor 1', 'Valor 2', 'Valor 3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Algo que possa estar errado é o seguinte trecho:

```
 echo "var tags = ". $js_array. ";\n";
 echo "var contagem = ". $array2. ";\n";
```

Pois como o json_encode retorna uma string, é necessário colocar aspas tenta desta maneira:

```
echo "var tags = '". $js_array. "';\n";
echo "var contagem = '". $array2. "';\n";
```

Comment: Bilico, nao é necessário colocar as aspas pois eu estou a igualar as variáveis dentro do php e no javascript quando eu faço alert, os valores dentro da variável aparecem corretamente no entanto estamos a nos desviar da pergunta.. Como é que eu faço para introduzir cada array dentro daquela variável "data". Exemplo: em vez de ter ['Work',5] , eu queria [variavel tags, variavel contagem].

Comment: tente no PHP fazer o seguinte array:
$array['tags' => $js_array, 'contagem' => $array2];
json_encode($array);

Comment: para depois utilizar no javascript: JSON.parse('$array'); então você terá um objeto JSON